# Constructor Injection with Action<bool> delegate in C#

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, constructor-injection

Problem is that I need to inject dependency(Constructor dependency) between some handle class and some console application.
Console application have state *isRunning*, which is obviously, bool variable. I could call *exit* command from console application, and then there is the problem. Since **bool** is value type, when we pass it as constructor parameter to some class, and then change it's value in that class, state of console application doesn't change. So I need to inject dependency.
I have code like this.

```
private static class Program
{
    private static bool isRunning = true;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...
        var exitHandler = new ExitHandler(isRunning);
        do
        {
            exitHandler.Exit();
        }
        while (isRunning);
    }
}
... 
public class ExitHandler
{
   ...
   private readonly Action<bool> applicationState;
   ...
   public void Exit();

}
```

I know we can wrap bool value into class and than pass it as parameter, but somehow it can be done with Action delegate. **The question is HOW?**

Comment: My question is "what are you trying to achieve?"  There may be a better way to do what you want to do (actually, there likely is a better way), but I can't quite see your end goal (having a `while` loop that continually calls `Exit`, for example, throws me off)

Comment: @Flydog57 It's just an example. In my application I get requests to call some command, among them also an 'exit' command. All commands are incapsulated in each classes - command handlers. Hope you understood)
And I know there is a better way, but someone told me that this migth work, so I was curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Action can "capture" a local variable or field.  So this is as simple as:

```
internal class Program
{
    static bool isRunning = true;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var exitHandler = new ExitHandler(() => isRunning = false) ;
        do
        {
            exitHandler.Exit();
        }
        while (isRunning);
    }
}
public class ExitHandler
{
    Action onExit;
    public ExitHandler(Action onExit)
    {
        this.onExit = onExit;
    }
   public void Exit() => onExit();

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Totally forget about variable capturing)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you could just use a `CancellationTokenSource`

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var exitHandler = new CancellationTokenSource();
        do
        {
            exitHandler.Cancel();
        }
        while (!exitHandler.IsCancellationRequested);
    }
}
```

It's simpler and, as a bonus, thread-safe.